# The batch changes the vbs code making it unreadable for the vbs to use

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

The batch changes the vbs code making it unreadable for the vbs to use. How do i fix this?

Batch code:

```
echo Const HIGH = 128 >> prio.vbs
echo strComputer = "." >> prio.vbs
echo Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ >> prio.vbs
echo    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") >> prio.vbs
echo Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ >> prio.vbs
echo    ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'file.exe'") >> prio.vbs
echo For Each objProcess in colProcesses >> prio.vbs
echo    objProcess.SetPriority(HIGH)  >> prio.vbs
echo Next >> prio.vbs
```

VBS orginal:

```
Const HIGH = 128
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'file.exe'")
For Each objProcess in colProcesses
    objProcess.SetPriority(HIGH) 
Next
```

VBS After :

```
Const HIGH = 128 
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ 
Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ 
   ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'file.exe'") 
For Each objProcess in colProcesses 
   objProcess.SetPriority(HIGH)  
Next
```

help please

Answer (score 3):

`&` characters have a special meaning in `CMD` (command-chaining), so you have to escape them to get literal ampersands:

```
echo    ^& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" ^& strComputer ^& "\root\cimv2") >> prio.vbs
```

The same is also true for closing parenthesis ')' and '<', '>'

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create another file, also, don't need any escaping to do it if you can save your vbs code with bat hybrid format:

```
<!-- :
@echo off && mode 050,03 && title <nul && title .\%~nx0 
for /f ^tokens^=* %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%wScript.exe "%~dpnx0?.wsf" ^& cls')do exit /b 2>nul >nul
--> <job> <script language = "vbscript">Const HIGH = 128 : strComputer = ".": Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" &_
"{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2"): Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select *"&_
"from Win32_Process Where Name = 'file.exe'"): For Each objProcess in colProcesses: objProcess.SetPriority(HIGH): Next </script></job>
```

So, don't need any escaping, just execute in command line or click then!

About layout:

---

```
<!-- :
@echo off && mode 050,03 && title <nul && title .\%~nx0 
for /f ^tokens^=* %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%wScript.exe "%~dpnx0?.wsf" ^& cls')do exit /b 2>nul >nul
--> <job> <script language = "vbscript">

:: your vbs code here ::

</script></job>
```